# Swift - Unable to read/write from file

Tags: ios, swift, file, read-write

I'm actually not sure whether I'm not able to read or unable to write. I'm pretty sure writing works. I'm using **Swift**.

[Here](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil) are my project files.

I'm trying to write an array of arrays to a file, and then read that array of arrays when the app launches. Here's my code for writing and reading, respectively. `listOfTasks` is my array of arrays variable.

Writing:

```
let cocoaArray : NSArray = listOfTasks
cocoaArray.writeToFile(String(fileURL), atomically: true)
```

Reading:

```
listOfTasks = NSArray(contentsOfFile: String(fileURL)) as! [Array<String>]
```

`fileURL`:

```
let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last

let fileURL = documentsDirectory!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")
```

I'm happy to provide additional information as necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of objects are in the array? Show how you create the value for `fileURL`.

Comment: whats your fileURL?

Comment: try `NSArray(contentsOfURL: fileURL)`

Comment: You know that `[Array<String>]` is equivalent to `Array<Array<String>>`, which is equivalent to `[[String]]`, right?

Comment: @redent84 Actually, no, I didn't. I learned something new! I'm pretty new to Swift, so excuse my not drawing connections.

Comment: I guess that you're saving a `[String]` and trying to retrieve a `[[String]]` and therefore is failing.

Comment: I took a look at your code, you're missing some basics. For example, `var listOfTasks = [[String(),String(),String()]]` creates a `[[String]]` (array of array of strings) with **one** element, which is an array containing **three empty strings**. That's probably not what you're expecting. Probably `var listOfTasks = [[String]]()` is what you were trying.

Comment: @redent84 No, that's what I want. If you downloaded my files you'll see the three fields in my prototype cell. The three strings go into those.

Comment: I downloaded your files, and saw that you're instantiating an array with ONE  (that it's an array of three empty strings `String()` ) element and then you're appending more elements. I don't think that you wanted that first element. If you wanted an array of three strings, you probably want to use an array of string tuples: `[(String, String, String)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where's exactly your problem, but here's a full working Playground sample:

```
let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/foo.plist") // Your path here
let array = [["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"], ["One", "Two", "Three"]] // Your array of arrays here

// Save to file
(array as NSArray).writeToURL(fileUrl, atomically: true)

// Read from file
let savedArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: fileUrl) as! [[String]]

print(savedArray)
```